# Hide text input layout's error after editing the field's text

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to hide error on a text input layout after the user solves the error but I am not sure how to do that, given that the function afterTextChanged doesn't seem to work with it. How can I do this?

This is the part I'm talking about:

```
loginViewModel.loginFormState.observe(this, Observer {
           val loginState = it ?: return@Observer

           // disable login button unless fields are valid
           binding.btnLogin.isEnabled = loginState.isDataValid
           if (loginState.emailError != null) {
               binding.etEmail.error = getString(loginState.emailError)
           }
           if (loginState.passwordError != null) {
               binding.tfPassword.error = getString(loginState.passwordError)
           }
       })

       binding.etEmail.afterTextChanged {
           loginViewModel.loginDataChanged(
               binding.etEmail.text.toString(),
               binding.etPassword.text.toString()
           )
       }

       binding.etPassword.afterTextChanged {
           loginViewModel.loginDataChanged(
               binding.etEmail.text.toString(),
               binding.etPassword.text.toString()
           )
       }

private fun TextInputEditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
   this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
       override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
           afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
       }

       override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

       override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
   })
```

Even if the user writes the password correctly and they can click on a button I have, the error is still there, how can I make it go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your error lies in those lines:

```
if (loginState.emailError != null) {
   binding.etEmail.error = getString(loginState.emailError)
}
```

Now imagine `emailError` was `"some error"` once and now is `null`. The bindings' text will not be set again, so it's still `"some error"`. To fix this mistake replace it with:

```
binding.etEmail.error = if(loginState.emailError != null){
    getString(loginState.emailError)
} else {
     null
}
```

Do the same for your passwordError

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setError` method and pass `null` as argument. from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setError(java.lang.CharSequence))

> Sets an error message that will be displayed below our EditText. If
> the error is null, the error message will be cleared.

you can call this method in afterTextChanged as

```
textInputEditText.addTextChangedListener (object: TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)    { }
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
         textInputLayout.error = null
    }
})
```